# getting infinite loop - adding scope on user model with traits

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

after adding the following trait to the user model, I get a 500 error because of an infinite loop.

```
    trait Multitenantable
    {
        public static function bootMultitenantable()
        {
            static::addGlobalScope('tenant_id', function (Builder $builder) {
                $tenant_id = 1;
                if ( auth()->check() )
                {
                    $tenant_id = Auth::user()->tenant_id;
                }
    
                $builder->where('tenant_id', '=', $tenant_id);
            });
        }
    }
```

when I remove either the trait from the user model or the if containing the auth() part (lines 7,8,9,10) from this trait, the infinite loop resolves.

I'm not familiar with the magic behind laravel, could someone explain why this happens?

and how I could add global scope for multitenancy to the user model like the others?

I've followed [this instruction](https://laraveldaily.com/simple-laravel-multi-tenancy-with-single-trait/) to add multitenancy to my laraval project.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by creating trait and used the trait on user model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait FilterByClass
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        if( request()->session()->exists('auth')){
        $user = auth()->user();
            self::addGlobalScope(function(Builder $builder)use($user){
                if($user->hasRole('Head Teacher')){
                    return;
                }
                $builder->where('branch_id',$user->class_id);
            });

        }
       
    }
}
```

I figured the loop happens because you are trying to authenticate from the user model and at the same time the model is looking for an authenticated user hence use are deadlocked.
so by checking if an `request()->session()->exist('auth')`  exist before applying the scope will make sure it check for an `auth()->user()` only if it exist.

Comment: I printed all the session variables but there is no such 'auth' key in the session. instead laravel uses a "login_web_{ hashed key }" pattern to store the login info.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when I add the auth condition to this trait, I cannot add the trait to user model.
If I do, when the user model is booting, It must check the Auth, wich requires booting the user model. And this cause the infinite loop.